# How to split a big line into more lines but only after the 5th character group with "@"?

Tags: notepad++

I have a big line like this in notepad++

> @asdasd @dsdsds @dosos @sdisidisi @diisdisidi @dfidifidif @ofodofodf ....

I want to split this line in more lines. Each with only 5 "@" character groups

> @asdasd @dsdsds @dosos @sdisidisi @diisdisidi
>   @dfidifidif @ofodofodf ....

and so on ..

How can I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

- Find what: `(@.*?@.*?@.*?@.*?@.*?\s)`
- Replace with: `\1\r\n`
- Option *Regular expression* must be checked

  <sub>**Before**</sub>
  [image]

  <sub>**After**</sub>
  [image]

**Note:** There might be a cleaner solution by counting occurrences `@{5}` together with a look-ahead. But Notepad++ uses the Scintilla regex engine and its still a limited one even in newer versions where they changed a lot regarding regex